# why cant I see a checkbox next to each list item

Tags: html, knockout.js

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="section-divider">
            <span>&nbsp;Assigned Delivery Centres&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="target click-zone" data-bind="foreach: target">
            <li class="icon arrow-right" data-bind="text: CentreName, click: unassociate"><input type="checkbox" title="Default delivery centre" class="checkbox" /></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

my list shows, but I dont get any checlboxes

Comment: when I copy paste your code I see a checkbox... Maybe look at your CSS code

Comment: Can you show the view model you're binding to?  As well as some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is just fine. Your problem will be in your CSS file. Could you put that in the question as well?

Otherwise, we can't see where the fault is. You should check your CSS and debug it.

```html
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="section-divider">
                <span>&nbsp;Assigned Delivery Centres&nbsp;</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="target click-zone" data-bind="foreach: target">
                <li class="icon arrow-right" data-bind="text: CentreName, click: unassociate"><input type="checkbox" title="Default delivery centre" class="checkbox" /></li>
            </ul>
    
        </div>
```

As you can see in this snippet there is a checkbox.